# split a number sequence into balanced groups

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization, discrete-optimization

Given a sequence of real numbers, ${a_1,a_2,...,a_n}$, I want to split them into $\textbf{m}$ groups ($\textbf{m}$ is fixed and $m<n$).

If the sum of each group is termed as $s_j$, how to setup the splitting algorithm so that the maximum $s_j$ is the smallest?

Any solutions or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the problem via mixed integer linear programming as follows.  Let binary decision variable $x_{i,j}$ indicate whether item $i$ is assigned to group $j$.  Let $z$ represent $\max_j s_j$.  The problem is to minimize $z$ subject to
\begin{align}
z &\ge \sum_i a_i x_{i,j} &&\text{for all $j$} \\
\sum_j x_{i,j} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i$}
\end{align}
You can also think of this problem as scheduling jobs on $m$ parallel machines to minimize the makespan.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is exactly what I am look for.